# Can we integrate google docs with windows azure

Tags: azure, google-docs, azure-storage, google-docs-api

I have a application where the documents will be uploaded to windows azure storage blobs, Since azure does not support for online viewing ,editing and sharing the documents , Can i integrate google docs feature with documents stored in azure storage blobs ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't integrate Google Docs with documents stored in Azure Blob Storage. Google docs (online viewing, editing, collaborating) is only available for documents stored at Google Docs app online! You could probably use Google Docs API (or SkyDrive api, which also supports online editing, viewing, sharing, collaboration) to upload documents to the respective store directly!